# Content of <button> vertically centered, but content of <a> not, why?

Tags: html, css

I have an anchor tag and a button tag, both styled button-like. However, while the "b" of the button is vertically centered, the "a" is not. Why? Which css property did I forget?

```css
.c-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a class="c-btn" href="#">a</a>
<button class="c-btn">b</button>
```

Comment: Try `line-height: 100px`

Comment: That was my workaround too, but I am trying to understand the difference.

Comment: this is the browser button default behavior

Comment: any way to apply that default behaviour to the anchor tag, or vice versa?

Comment: You can also use a pseudo element to vertical-align the text https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/oGxRJw (if text has to wrap, then it should be wrapped https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/EwKzMg ), or display:inline-flex https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/EwKzrg

Comment: Thank you G-Cyr, these are some fantastic workarounds!